# Speadsheet.getRangeByName is undefined

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getRangeByName(String)), there is a function named `getRangeByName(String)` in class Spreadsheet but it seems to be undefined for me.

```
function onEdit(e) {
    if (e) {
        var ss = e.source.getActiveSheet();
        Logger.log(ss.getName);  
        Logger.log(ss.getRange);
        Logger.log(ss.getRangeByName);
    }   
}
// outputs:
//  function getName() {/* */}
//  function getRange() {/* */}
//  undefined
```

Is this because `event.source.getActiveSheet()` returns something else other than a `Spreadsheet` object, which contradicts the official documentation (screenshot)?

[image](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events)

If that's the case, how can I get a range by name on the active sheet from the event's source? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By doing `var ss = e.source.getActiveSheet();` the variable `ss` is Sheet type, not of type Spreadsheet, so the problem. The method [`getRangeByName(name)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet?hl=en#getRangeByName%28String%29) belongs to Spreadsheet.

Try the following:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
    if (e) {
        var ss = e.source;
        var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
        Logger.log(s.getName);  
        Logger.log(s.getRange);
        Logger.log(ss.getRangeByName);
    }   
}
//  outputs:
//  function getName() {/* */}
//  function getRange() {/* */}
//  function getRangeByName() {/* */}
```